# Write a groovy method to extract all nested classes with an annotated field

Tags: groovy, annotations

I create the object and then try adding them to a list. It is able to build the map, but the problem is that the object graph is complex and the solution is not maintanable

```
Person person=new Person(name:"Dennis Carter",department:"Engineering",manager..)

Retail retail=Retail(field :"Fixed Price", p:person)
list l=[]

//manually add to list

l<<person.manager
l<<manager.department
l<< manager.address
//etc

//...
Finder f=new Finder(l)
println "Manp is ${f.myMap"

class Finder {
    Finder(def obj){
        for(element in obj )
            addToMap(element)
    }

    def myMap=[:]

    def addToMap( obj) {
        def ops=[]
        def fans=[]
        if(obj){
            ops= obj.class.declaredFields
            for(Field f : ops ){
                fans=   f.annotations
                for(Annotation an : fans){
                    if(an.annotationType()==myAnnot) {
                        MyAnnot well=(MyAnnot)an
                        myMap[well.used()]=well.type()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        println "Your map is finally ${myMap}"
    }
}

class Retail {
    @MyAnnot
    String field
    Person p
}

class Person{
    @MyAnnot
    String name

    @MyAnnot
    Manager currentManager

    //...
}

class Manager{
    @MyAnnot
    String name
}
```

I want to be able to visit the object graph and find all nested classes with the annotation `@MyAnnot`. The Person class for example has no annotation but its nested fields have the MyAnnot annotation and so on

Comment: what have you tried? do you have any particular problem or asking SO to write code for you?

Comment: I have tried the following,

Comment: The solutiion I tried is as shown, However it isn't maintainable. I would like to use something more dynamic, so that new objects can be added without manually adding to the list

Comment: What does `MyAnnot.used()` should return?

Comment: @MyAnnot{ String used() default "",  String type() default ""}